# "Missing grant-type parameter" in Auth0 Delegation endpoint call

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, postman, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

I'm trying to call (POST) the Auth0 delegation endpoint from Postman with the following request, as suggested by Auth0:

```
Content-Type: 'application/json'

{
  "client_id":   "{CLIENT_ID}",
  "grant_type":  "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
  "id_token":    "{YOUR_ID_TOKEN}",
  "target":      "lwTL1rYVfC0KsBUFPeKWY3HvGjbIgdDM",
  "api_type":    "salesforce_api",
  "scope":       "openid"
}
```

I'm getting this error, even though the grant_type parameter ***is*** included in the above request:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing grant_type parameter"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please include the code for the request you are sending.    Please remove Google-oauth tag it doesnt apear you are using Googles oauth servers

Comment: @DaImTo: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying this from Postman Client. So there is no code. Just added the header and pasted the above request body in the body and making a POST.

Comment: This error can be caused by not properly setting the content-type Beyond that i cant help without being able to test your code.  please include https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The [Auth0 docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#database-ad-ldap-active-) indicate you've got it right, but [another page implementing OAuth2](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-jwt-bearer-token-authorization-grant-type/) suggests the grant_type might need to be URL-encoded, i.e. replacing `:` with `%3A` in each case. Is that any help?

Comment: @DaImTo: At present there is no code, I am only trying it from the POSTMAN Client. Can you please suggest how I can include stackoverflow.com/help/mcve? should I add it to the tag?

Comment: @bouteillebleu: Thanks for your reply. I tried replacing all : with %3A but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Postman has specific instructions and "helpers" for OAuth 2.0 as described here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization

Comment: @jwilleke: Thanks for your comment. I checked that out. When I tried to check the Postman Console, I 'm not sure why there are no entries for my POSTs :(

Comment: Nat: What DalmTo means is to click the link, read about MCVE, and then to include one in your answer. Nat & @DaImTo: However, the MCVE comment ***is not applicable is this case***. The post request supplied in the question is as close to a working MCVE as you can get, as it is not appropriate to supply a working client ID or token ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Auth0's new [OIDC Conformant Authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/intro#delegation) docs:

> **Delegation**
>
> Given that [ID tokens should no longer be used as API tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/api-tokens) and that [refresh tokens should be used only at the token endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/refresh-tokens), this endpoint is now considered deprecated.
>
> At the moment there is no OIDC-compliant mechanism to obtain third-party API tokens. In order to facilitate a gradual migration to the new authentication pipeline, delegation can still be used to obtain third-party API tokens. This will be deprecated in future releases.

Also, from Auth0's [Using AWS with Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws/tokens) docs:

> **Legacy Grant Types**
>
> As of 8 June 2017, new Auth0 customers cannot add any of the legacy grant types to their clients, which are required for use with the [Delegation endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-token-info). Legacy grant types are only available for previous customers while they migrate to new flows, to avoid breaking changes. To find the secure alternative for your case refer to [Secure Alternatives to the Legacy Grant Types](https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types#secure-alternatives-to-the-legacy-grant-types).

Reading further from the [Secure Alternatives to the Legacy Grant Types](https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types#secure-alternatives-to-the-legacy-grant-types) link:

> **Legacy Grant Type**
>
> `http://auth0.com/oauth/legacy/grant-type/ro/jwt-bearer`
>
> **Alternative**
>
> This feature is disabled by default. If you would like this feature enabled, please [contact support](https://support.auth0.com/) to discuss your use case and prevent the possibility of introducing security vulnerabilities.

More info on legacy grant types can also be found [here](https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types#grant-types-available).

---

So, the problem you are having is that Delegation has been deprecated. That means the `/delegation` endpoint and more importantly the `jwt-bearer` grant type, have been deprecated. If you are a new customer, you are out of luck. If you are an existing customer you need to contact support to get it enabled.

As to why Postman returns the cryptic `"Missing grant_type parameter"` error as opposed to the much better `"Grant type 'http://auth0.com/oauth/legacy/grant-type/delegation/id_token not allowed for the client."` error you get with other browser extension based REST Clients, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @Nat If you are interested you could take the [Tour]. Another useful, and hard to find, link, is the [community moderated FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: Sure, Thanks Robin!