# Is delegation deprecated in Auth0?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

I'm trying to POST to a Auth0 delegation URL to obtain an access token and getting a "Grant Type not allowed" error as seen below. (This is when *not* using Postman.)

I came across a post in the forums that Delegation is deprecate in Auth0. Can anyone confirm if that is the issue here and if I'm trying something that's not available anymore?

Request:

```
Content-Type: 'application/json'

{
  "client_id":   "ID",
  "grant_type":  "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
  "id_token":    "TOKEN",
  "target":      "lwTL1rYVfC0KsBUFPeKWY3HvGjbIgdDM",
  "api_type":    "salesforce_api",
  "scope":       "openid"
}
```

Error:

```
{
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "Grant type 'http://auth0.com/oauth/legacy/grant-type/delegation/id_token' not allowed for the client.",
"statusCode": 403,
"error_uri": "https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types"
}
```

Related Question:

["Missing grant-type parameter" in Auth0 Delegation endpoint call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014198/missing-grant-type-parameter-in-auth0-delegation-endpoint)

In that question, using Postman to call the endpoint with the same request results in a different error!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Missing grant-type parameter" in Auth0 Delegation endpoint call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014198/missing-grant-type-parameter-in-auth0-delegation-endpoint-call)

Comment: Yes, Delegation, the `/delegation` endpoint and the `jwt-bearer` grant type have been deprecated. See your other question for the details.

Comment: @robinCTS: Thanks for your comment. Yes the error in the other question was not intutive. Just said grant type missing. But this in a different client is more intutive of the deprecation. Thanks again!